# How to know new data in Firebase cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How do you know if the data is not changing and what's new in Firebase Cloud functions? I've tried several different options to flag that if the data is just changed, then I do not send push notification. Also I tried to get from snapshot _newData
  And _data child nodes to compare the number, and if __newData is greater, then this is a new record, but it did not work. Please tell me how it can be done.

A snippet of example code.

```
   module.exports = functions.database.ref('/userListEvents/{userID}')
        .onWrite(event => {

            const snapshot = event.data;

            if (event.data.val() && !event.data.previous.val()) {
                console.log('send push notification');
            } else if (snapshot._data) {
                console.log('send push notification');
            } else {
                return console.log('data was removed');
            };
    }
```

Ref

```
functions.database.ref('/cards/{cardID}/interestedUsers')
    .onWrite(event => {
```

Updated: This option does not work for me, because if I do eg `functions.database.ref ('/ userListEvents / {userID} / {eventID}')`, then an error is reported that the field must not be empty.

I tried so but I didn't get a good result.

```
if (event.data.val() && !event.data.previous.val()) {
        console.log('send push notification');
    } else if (event.data.val() && event.data.previous.val()) {
        const newData = event.data.val();
        const previousData = event.data.previous.val();
        console.log('newData', newData, 'previousData', previousData);
        const newDataKeys = Object.keys(newData);
        const previousDataKeys = Object.keys(previousData);

        if (newDataKeys.length > previousDataKeys.length) {
            console.log('send push', newDataKeys.length, previousDataKeys.length);
        } else {
            return console.log('just update data', newDataKeys.length, previousDataKeys.length);
        }
    } else {
        return console.log('removed data')
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare using `event.data.current.val()` not `event.data.val()`.  Example:

```
exports.detectChange = functions.database.ref('/userListEvents/{userID}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        const crnt = event.data.current;
        const prev = event.data.previous;

        if (crnt.val() && !prev.val()) {
            // value created
            console.log('Created: send push notification');
        } else if (!crnt.val() && prev.val()) {
            // value removed
            console.log('Removed: send push notification');
        } else {
            // value updated
            console.log('Updated');
        }
     });
```

Comment: Tell me please, and you can use two dynamic keys for example functions.database.ref('/userListEvents/{userID}/{requestID}’) ?

Comment: @Alexsander: Yes, multiple keys are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Check the example below:

```
exports.Observedata = functions.database.ref("/location/{id}").onWrite((event) => {
  const id = event.params.id;
  const snap = event.data;
  if (!snap.exists() && snap.previous.exists()) {
    //deleted data
  } else if (snap.exists() && !snap.previous.exists()) {
    //newly addded data
  } else if (!snap.child("isactive").val() && snap.child("isactive").changed()) {
    //if the node isactive changed its value from false to true
  }
});
```

Comment: please look on update: This option does not work for me, because if I do eg functions.database.ref ('/ userListEvents / {userID} / {eventID}'), then an error is reported that the field must not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you have, other than what has already been published here, is to use the `changed()` method as a flag to indicate if a given reference has changed or not. Example:

```
exports sampleFunction = functions.database.ref('/userListEvents/${userId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    var eventSnapshot = event.data;
    if (eventSnapshot.changed()) {
      // Here you know something has changed
    }
  });
```

Although it doesn't tell you **what** has changed it is a simple way to know if **something** has changed under a given node. There is [another example in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?#monitoring_changed_values).