# Firebase function to timestamp last change runs multiple times

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function to timestamp an item when it is updated. I have seen other examples where code gets stuck in an infinite loop because the timestamp for the latest update causes it to run again, but I thought I had that part figured out in my code below. I believe this was working fine at one point, now it seems to get stuck in an update loop. Am I missing something?

```
exports.itemUpdate = functions.database.ref('/items/{id}').onUpdate((event) => {
    //dont mark updated timestamp if item is deleted
    if (!event.data.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    //dont update if we are simply updating timestamp
    if (event.data.child('lastUpdated').changed()) {
        return null;
    }else{
        return admin.database().ref('/items/' + event.params.id + '/lastUpdated').set(admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    }
});
```

Please note, this is for pre v1.0 beta version of firebase functions.

Comment: are there any errors in the function logs? I don't understand your call to `changed`, does this method exists? I don't see it in the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot

Comment: I saw a reference to it in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047431/how-to-know-new-data-in-firebase-cloud-functions), and and there are no errors. This also seems to fire if the the item does not exist so I end up with an empty item that just has an lastUpdated stamp and nothing else....

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it better in the morning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your code is not getting into the `if` block, as there's no method `changed` in the [dataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot#).

You could try to check if `lastUpdated` changed with something like this:

```
const oldValue = event.data.previous.val();
const newValue = event.data.val();

if(oldValue.lastUpdated !== newValue.lastUpdated) {
  return null;
} else {
  return admin.database().ref('/items/' + event.params.id + '/lastUpdated').set(admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);   
}
```

Comment: I can't find the changed() method in the documentation either, but it appears to work if I output it too the console. Hopefully someone can weigh in and clarify that part of it. Thanks